# writing a function using multiple variables

Tags: functions, list-manipulation

I am fairly new to *Mathematica* and am trying to write a function for the equation:

```
xx = [x/(Sqrt[h^2 + d^2 + y^2]))*(Sqrt[h^2 + (d + yy)^2])
```

where h, d are known and x, y and yy are functions that give lists of numbers of equal list length. Is there a way to write a function that encompasses all the variables x, y, yy? I'm assuming it would start with

```
xx[x_, y_, yy_] := .........
```

or is the best method to create a loop?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I formatted your code for you. [See this page](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help) to learn how that is done. By the way, your brackets don't match. The first one should be a round parenthesis. You should check out the answers to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18393/8) and the links from [this part of the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/VariablesAndFunctions.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loop construct is necessary. Assuming that h, and d are constants defined at toplevel, and that you have the functions `x`, `y` and `yy` defined, you could proceed as follows:

```
hsq = h^2

xlist = x[...]

ylist = y[...]

yylist = yy[...]

xx[x_, y_, yy_] := x/(Sqrt[hsq + d^2 + y^2])*(Sqrt[hsq + (d + yy)^2])

xxlist = MapThread[xx, {xlist, ylist, yylist}]
```

The `MapThread` function will pluck successive items from `xlist`, `ylist`, and `yylist`, pass them to `xx` and gather up the computed values in a list which it returns.

This isn't the most sophisticated way to solve your problem with *Mathematica*, but at this point of your *Mathematica* experience, it may be the quickest and easiest way for you to do the calculations you want to carry out.

Your expression for xx isn't syntactically correct. I made a guess about where the parentheses go. Another interpretation I could have made is

```
xx[x_, y_, yy_] := x/((Sqrt[hsq + d^2 + y^2])*(Sqrt[hsq + (d + yy)^2]))
```

Use whichever is correct.